# Mostra datos en ListView de manera inversa

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un **ArrayList** de tipo *ArrayList v_DtCajasTarimasLista* y cada vez que ingreso datos nuevos se agregan correctamente y se muestran en el ListView, pero lo que pasa es que el último registro ingresado aparece hasta la parte inferior del ListView y lo que necesito es lo contrario que aparezca al inicio del ListView.

> Como se tendría que hacer para invertir el orden de valores del `ListView`?

Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Gracias

Mi código:

```
v_DtCajasTarimas = new ListaDtCajasTarimas();
                    v_DtCajasTarimas.setV_itemCode(codigo);
                    v_DtCajasTarimas.setV_status("");
                    v_DtCajasTarimas.setIdLinea(contCajas);
                    v_DtCajasTarimasLista.add(v_DtCajasTarimas);
adaptadorListaCajaTarima = new AdaptadorListaCajaTarima(getMyActivity(), v_DtCajasTarimasLista);
                    adaptadorListaCajaTarima.setObjetosGenerales(objetosGenerales);
                    adaptadorListaCajaTarima.setAppCompatActivity(getAppCompatActivity());
                    adaptadorListaCajaTarima.setItemFragment(this);
                    listViewCajaTarima.setAdapter(adaptadorListaCajaTarima);
```

Comment: agrega como configuras los datos en el ListView, en el adapter

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys ya lo agregue

Comment: Gracias @JavierFr recuerda que debes aportar más información y que tu pregunta tenga buena redacción para que sea entendible, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes un List de elementos y deseas invertir el orden puedes usar [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) o [Collections.reverse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) antes de agregar los datos al `Adapter` de tu `ListView`:

```
Collections.sort(listElementos);
```

o

```
   Collections.reverse(listElementos);
```

En el caso de tu código cambia el orden antes de asignarlos al `Adapter`, usando [Collections.reverse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) cambiara el orden de los elementos dentro del `List` :

```
Collections.reverse(v_DtCajasTarimasLista)
adaptadorListaCajaTarima = new AdaptadorListaCajaTarima(getMyActivity(), v_DtCajasTarimasLista);
```